# User profile in craft 4 - first name and last name fields are gone

Tags: users

I noticed that first name and last name fields in control panel user profile are gone. There is just full name field instead. Is there some kind of setting that would bring first name and last name back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The “First Name” and “Last Name” fields were replaced with a new “Full Name” field in Craft 4. While the fields are gone, the First/Last Name values are automatically parsed from the Full Name whenever a user is saved. Also, the `users/save-user` action still supports posting separate `firstName`/`lastName` values, which are automatically merged into `fullName` on save.

This is explained at https://github.com/craftcms/cms/pull/10624